# Kubelet metrics not appearing in prometheus

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, amazon-eks

I have to setup a monitoring environment for my EKS cluster.
Prometheus is running on external node and I am trying to use node exporter daemonset for getting metrics.
But on prometheus when I see the targets I am not able to see any target instead of just local host.

**Kubernetes_sd_config block**

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
scrape_configs:

- job_name: 'prometheus'
  scrape_interval: 15s
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9100']


- job_name: 'kubernetes-apiservers'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    api_server: https://{{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token
  scheme: https
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    action: keep
    regex: default;kubernetes;https
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: {{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}


- job_name: 'kubernetes-kube-state'
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
    api_server: https://{{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token
  scheme: https
  relabel_configs:
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_pod_name
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_grafanak8sapp]
    regex: .*true.*
    action: keep
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: {{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
  - source_labels: ['__meta_kubernetes_pod_label_daemon', '__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name']
    regex: 'node-exporter;(.*)'
    action: replace
    target_label: nodename
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    regex: (.+);(.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: /api/v1/namespaces/${1}/pods/${2}/proxy/metrics

###################################################################################
# Scrape config for nodes (kubelet).                                              #
#                                                                                 #
# Rather than connecting directly to the node, the scrape is proxied though the   #
# Kubernetes apiserver.  This means it will work if Prometheus is running out of  #
# cluster, or can't connect to nodes for some other reason (e.g. because of       #
# firewalling).                                                                   #
###################################################################################

- job_name: 'kubernetes-kubelet'
  scheme: https
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token

  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: node
    api_server: https://{{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token
  relabel_configs:
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: {{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics

- job_name: 'kubernetes-cadvisor'
  scheme: https
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: node
    api_server: https://{{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token
  relabel_configs:
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: {{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_node_name]
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: /api/v1/nodes/${1}/proxy/metrics/cadvisor


###################################################################################
# Example scrape config for service endpoints.                                    #
#                                                                                 #
# The relabeling allows the actual service scrape endpoint to be configured       #
# for all or only some endpoints.                                                 #
###################################################################################

- job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints'

  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    api_server: https://{{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token

  relabel_configs:
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_name

#########################################################################################
# Example scrape config for probing services via the Blackbox Exporter.                 #
#                                                                                       #
# The relabeling allows the actual service scrape endpoint to be configured             #
# for all or only some services.                                                        #
#########################################################################################

- job_name: 'kubernetes-services'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: service
    api_server: https://{{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token
  scheme: https
  tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
  bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token 
  relabel_configs:
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: {{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    regex: (.+);(.+)
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    replacement: /api/v1/namespaces/$1/services/$2/proxy/metrics

##################################################################################
# Example scrape config for pods                                                 #
#                                                                                #
# The relabeling allows the actual pod scrape to be configured                   #
# for all the declared ports (or port-free target if none is declared)           #
# or only some ports.                                                            #
##################################################################################

- job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'

  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: pod
    api_server: https://{{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_example_io_scrape_port]
    action: replace
    regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
    replacement: $1:$2
    target_label: __address__
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_pods 
- job_name: 'kubernetes-service-endpoints-e'
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    api_server: https://{{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
    bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token
  scheme: https
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  bearer_token_file: /etc/prometheus/token
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
    action: keep
    regex: true
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
    action: replace
    regex: (\d+)
    target_label: __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    action: replace
    regex: ()
    target_label: __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path
    replacement: /metrics
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace, __meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number, __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
    target_label: __metrics_path__
    regex: (.+);(.+);(.+);(.+)
    replacement: /api/v1/namespaces/$1/services/$2:$3/proxy$4
  - target_label: __address__
    replacement: {{ kubernetes_api_server_addr }}
  - action: labelmap
    regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_namespace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: kubernetes_name
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name]
    action: replace
    target_label: instance
```

This is the Prometheus.yml file that I have on my prometheus instance.

**Prometheus instance logs /var/log/messages**

```
Jul  1 15:18:53 ip-XXXXXXXXXXX prometheus: ts=2021-07-01T15:18:53.655Z caller=log.go:124 component=k8s_client_runtime level=debug func=Verbose.Infof msg="Listing and watching *v1.Endpoints from pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.21.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:167"
Jul  1 15:18:53 ip-XXXXXXXXXXX prometheus: ts=2021-07-01T15:18:53.676Z caller=log.go:124 component=k8s_client_runtime level=debug func=Infof msg="GET https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0  in 20 milliseconds"
Jul  1 15:18:53 ip-XXXXXXXXXXX prometheus: ts=2021-07-01T15:18:53.676Z caller=log.go:124 component=k8s_client_runtime level=error func=ErrorDepth msg="pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.21.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1.Endpoints: failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get \"https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0\": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
Jul  1 15:18:56 ip-XXXXXXXXXXX prometheus: ts=2021-07-01T15:18:56.445Z caller=log.go:124 component=k8s_client_runtime level=debug func=Verbose.Infof msg="Listing and watching *v1.Pod from pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.21.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:167"
Jul  1 15:18:56 ip-XXXXXXXXXXX prometheus: ts=2021-07-01T15:18:56.445Z caller=log.go:124 component=k8s_client_runtime level=debug func=Infof msg="GET https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/pods?limit=500&resourceVersion=0  in 0 milliseconds"
Jul  1 15:18:56 ip-XXXXXXXXXXX prometheus: ts=2021-07-01T15:18:56.445Z caller=log.go:124 component=k8s_client_runtime level=error func=ErrorDepth msg="pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.21.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1.Pod: failed to list *v1.Pod: Get \"https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/pods?limit=500&resourceVersion=0\": unable to read authorization credentials file /etc/prometheus/token: open /etc/prometheus/token: no such file or directory"
```

Comment: Please provide your kubernetes_sd_config block from your prometheus config file.

Comment: I have uploaded the code File...I am new to Kubernetes and prometheus..

Comment: when you look at service discovery, are you seeing dropped targets from the kubernetes cluster or are you seeing nothing at all?

Comment: I am able to see a single target  "localhost:9100" only.

Comment: then your prometheus is likely unable to authenticate onto the kubernetes cluster.  What logs are you seeing in your prometheus?  Can you increase its log level?

Comment: I have uploaded the promethus logs in the question at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The logs you shared point to the problem:

```
... unable to read authorization credentials file /etc/prometheus/token: open /etc/prometheus/token: no such file or directory"
```

The token file for in-cluster workloads is by default mounted at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` but since you mentioned Prometheus is running "on external node" (no idea what you mean by this) this may or may not be useful for you to be possible to change.

Comment: "on external node" means that I have configured Prometheus in an ec2 instance and I have API deployed on EKS cluster (which I want to monitor from prometheus). So , this has been kept on a separate instance so that if in future the cluster is down then too my monitoring infra is up and running. Moreover, I have successfully implemented this by using "Kube-state-metrics". But, I want to know why I was not able to do this using "Node exporter".